# Mysql union how to Group returned 3 rows into single row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

Mysql union how to Group returned 3 rows into single row

```
 ( 
    select CONCAT(c.Email,';', c.CCEmail,';', c.AdminEmail,';', c.HREmail) as Email 
    from companies c  
    Where companyid=#companyid# 
 ) 
    union
 ( 
    select ClaimAdministratorEmail 
    from claimadminregion
    where FIND_IN_SET(#companyid#, companyid)
 )
    union
 ( 
    select LossPreventionPersonEmail 
    from losspreventionregion
    where FIND_IN_SET(#companyid#, companyid)
 )
```

it return 3 rows but i want them in single row but don't know how

Comment: What's your end goal with this? Why does the query have to return one row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.Email,';', c.CCEmail,';', c.AdminEmail,';', c.HREmail,';', A.ClaimAdministratorEmail,';', B.LossPreventionPersonEmail) AS Email 
FROM companies c  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT #companyid# AS companyid, GROUP_CONCAT(ClaimAdministratorEmail SEPARATOR ';') ClaimAdministratorEmail 
           FROM claimadminregion WHERE FIND_IN_SET(#companyid#, companyid) 
          ) A ON c.companyid = A.companyid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT #companyid# AS companyid, GROUP_CONCAT(LossPreventionPersonEmail SEPARATOR ';') LossPreventionPersonEmail 
           FROM losspreventionregion WHERE FIND_IN_SET(#companyid#, companyid)
          ) B ON c.companyid = B.companyid
WHERE companyid=#companyid#
```

Comment: claimadminregion -> claimadminregion as A,
losspreventionregion -> losspreventionregion as B,
WHERE companyid=#companyid# -> WHERE c.companyid=#companyid#,
but not working return NULL

Comment: we can't use it like SELECT #companyid#, #companyid# is used as veriable

Comment: @Rik We can use `#companyid#` as column but we have to give `ALIAS` name to that column. I had updated that portion. That is needed because we want to compare `companyid` with primary key of `companies` table